# Using DigitalMicrograph calibrations in scripts

Tags: dm-script

I am trying to use rotations and calibrations between different microscope coordinate systems (e.g. beam tilt, stage shift, CCD image/diffraction pattern) in DigitalMicrograph by using the calibrations present in the "Microscope Data.gtg" file. To do this I load the file and pull out the different calibrations. Is there an easier way to access individual calibrations?

To determine the orientation of the stage the script needs to know at what Magnification the Stage calibration was performed. In old versions of DigitalMicrograph there was a global tag called "Calibrations:Stage Calibration:Acquisition Magnification". However I could not find this tag in GMS2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been changes in the code regarding calibrations between GMS 1 and GMS 2 which indeed are as you've described.

**There is no easy access to the required information via the scripting language.**

However, the solution you have described is indeed the best workaround.